# Noticing different behavior when updating playback status on iOS and Android using Expo's Audio Module

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio, expo

I'm currently attempting to implement an audio player in React Native using [Expo's Audio module](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/). Everything is working as expected in Android, but on iOS, the `playbackStatusUpdate()` callback does not appear to be working. I've pasted the relevant snippet below.

```
Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
    playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
    interruptionModeIOS: INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
    interruptionModeAndroid: INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
});

const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({ uri });
await sound.setProgressUpdateIntervalAsync(100);

sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((data) => {
    if (data.isLoaded) {
        setCurrentPosition(data.positionMillis);
        setIsPlaying(data.isPlaying);
        setClipDuration(data.durationMillis || 0);

        if (data.didJustFinish && !data.isLooping) {
            sound.setPositionAsync(0);
            options.onPlaybackComplete();
        }
    }
});
```

On iOS, the callback simply is not called at all, so no statuses, etc. are set.

I'm using the current position to update a slider at a higher level in my component tree. Again - this all works exactly as expected in Android. Any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: getting same issue